# How to use SVG Sprite with <use> element in Bootstrap

Tags: svg, icons, bootstrap-5

Im making a website using Bootstrap 5.0.2 and im also using bootstrap icons
so i wanted to copy this last icon grid [snippet](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/features/#:%7E:text=5d-,Icon%20grid,-Featured%20title) from bootstrap's website but the icons are not visible when i use it on my website even though i have icon's pack linked to my index.html inside of the code of that snippet they has used some code like

```
<svg class="bi text-muted flex-shrink-0 me-3" width="1.75em" height="1.75em"><use xlink:href="#cpu-fill"/></svg>
```

to add the icons the above code the adds a icon of some like processor but when i add this to my code it dosent show anything how do i use any icon from bootstrap website in this
<use .../> tag

i want to add this [icon](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/stack/) to my website in the same size as it appears on their [snippet page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/examples/features/#:%7E:text=5d-,Icon%20grid,-Featured%20title)

This is my index.html

```
<!-- Start of  Features -->
    <div style="background-color: #E7E7E7;" class="container-fluid">

      <section style="padding: 0;">

        <div class="container px-4 py-5" id="icon-grid">
          <!-- <h2 class="pb-2 border-bottom">Icon grid</h2> -->
      
          <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-lg-4 g-4 py-5">
            <div class="col d-flex align-items-start">
              **<svg class="bi text-muted flex-shrink-0 me-3" width="1.75em" height="1.75em"><use xlink:href="bootstrap-icons.svg#heart-fill"/></svg>**
              
              <!-- <i class="bi bi-stack bi text-muted flex-shrink-0 me-3"  width="3.0em" height="auto"></i> -->
              <div>
                <h4 class="fw-bold mb-0">Featured title</h4>
                <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-flex align-items-start">
              **<svg class="bi text-muted flex-shrink-0 me-3" width="1.75em" height="1.75em"><use xlink:href="#cpu-fill"/></svg>**
              <div>
                <h4 class="fw-bold mb-0">Featured title</h4>
                <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-flex align-items-start">
              **<svg class="bi text-muted flex-shrink-0 me-3" width="1.75em" height="1.75em"><use xlink:href="#calendar3"/></svg>**
              <div>
                <h4 class="fw-bold mb-0">Featured title</h4>
                <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-flex align-items-start">
              **<svg class="bi text-muted flex-shrink-0 me-3" width="1.75em" height="1.75em"><use xlink:href="#home"/></svg>**
              <div>
                <h4 class="fw-bold mb-0">Featured title</h4>
                <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-flex align-items-start">
              **<svg class="bi text-muted flex-shrink-0 me-3" width="1.75em" height="1.75em"><use xlink:href="#speedometer2"/></svg>**
              <div>
                <h4 class="fw-bold mb-0">Featured title</h4>
                <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-flex align-items-start">
              <svg class="bi text-muted flex-shrink-0 me-3" width="1.75em" height="1.75em"><use xlink:href="#toggles2"/></svg>
              <div>
                <h4 class="fw-bold mb-0">Featured title</h4>
                <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-flex align-items-start">
              <**svg class="bi text-muted flex-shrink-0 me-3" width="1.75em" height="1.75em"><use xlink:href="#geo-fill"/></svg>**
              <div>
                <h4 class="fw-bold mb-0">Featured title</h4>
                <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col d-flex align-items-start">
              **<svg class="bi text-muted flex-shrink-0 me-3" width="1.75em" height="1.75em"><use xlink:href="#tools"/></svg>**
              <div>
                <h4 class="fw-bold mb-0">Featured title</h4>
                <p>Paragraph of text beneath the heading to explain the heading.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </section>
    </div>

<!-- End of  Features -->
```

i want to add other icons from bootstrap icon
 where svg tag is there in above code in the same height and size as mentioned in the above code

i copied this snippet from bootstrap examples but the icons are not visible anyways i want to add other icons in same color and dimensions as they were there in the snippet